# How to create a draggable formula for alternating columns and rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh72N.png)

I have the following dataset x1 and x2. I need to combine it into 1 column X1,X2.

However, since the values alternates between rows and columns, I can't seem to find the right draggable formula to use.

My data set is really long and manually keying them it would be very tedious and prone to error.

I have tried using OFFSET and VLOOKUP on F3 and F4, then dragging it down, to no avail. As by dragging it down, it will skip rows.

I apologise for the poor description as I am new to excel. Would kindly appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `F3` and drag down

```
=INDEX($B$3:$C$8,INT((ROW()-2)/2+0.5),1+ISEVEN(ROW()))
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed function]

(you'll need to enclose this in an `IFERROR()` function if you plan to drag it down to more cells than you have data)